# How to display a live streaming video via Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, video-streaming

How can I stream video from live webcam with Silverlight?

Not from my camera, but transmit from some live camera I found in internet

(for example, 
http: //ac.lido.lv/kamera.php?lang=ru or
http://pendelcam.kip.uni-heidelberg.de/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=640x480)