# How to provide LIVE Video Streaming facility using Silverlight?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012, silverlight-5.0, live-streaming

I'm working on **Virtual Classroom Project**. I want to provide LIVE video streaming facility in my project. I don't want to add much functionality in it. Can anybody tell me how can I achieve it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Microsoft Encoder, in the following article there is a very good explanation about how to provide LIVE video streaming.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jitghosh/archive/2007/11/30/demo-live-streams-in-silverlight.aspx

also read this - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23190/Creating-Encoding-and-Delivering-Silverlight-Strea

you can also look at this question - [How to display a live streaming video via Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575390/how-to-display-a-live-streaming-video-via-silverlight)